# How is this class constructed?

Tags: c++

I am confused how the class inherits from the class RecursiveASTVisitor by passing itself as a template argument. Also, does writing Rewrite(R) in the line

```
MyRecursiveASTVisitor(Rewriter &R) : Rewrite(R) { }
```

assign the value R to the variable Rewrite? There is no class Rewrite defined anywhere in the code. Is the ":" operator used for things other than inheriting from a class?

```
class MyRecursiveASTVisitor
    : public RecursiveASTVisitor<MyRecursiveASTVisitor>
{

 public:
  MyRecursiveASTVisitor(Rewriter &R) : Rewrite(R) { }
  void InstrumentStmt(Stmt *s);
  bool VisitStmt(Stmt *s);
  bool VisitUnaryOperator(UnaryOperator *e);

  Rewriter &Rewrite;
};
```

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Google for CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) you will probably find a couple of good introductions to this technique

Comment: I updated my answer for your additional question. You may be confusing the definition for your class with the definitions of constructors for your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, this is known as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). This pattern is often implemented to provide a mechanism similar to virtual functions, but at compile time (static polymorphism). For example, `RecursiveASTVistor<T>` might contain a method that does the following:

```
...
//using T = MyRecursiveASTVisitor; for your specific case
T *concrete_visitor = static_cast<T*>(this);
concrete_visitor->VisitStmt(something);
```

If `VisitStmt` is defined in your `MyRecursiveASTVisitor` class, then that method is called, otherwise it calls the base definition provided by `RecursiveASTVistor`. Callers outisde of your class hierarchy also get to take advantage of this static polymorphism.

Here is a [short example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b9323e10376c4eb) to help you gain a better intuition of what's happening:

```
#include <iostream> 

template <class T>
struct Base {
    void foo() {
        T *concrete = static_cast<T*>(this);
        concrete->foo();
    };
    void bar() {std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {
    void foo() {std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    Base<Derived> b;
    b.foo();
    b.bar();
}
```

### Output

```
Derived
Base
```

**Edit**: To answer your additional question:

> Also, does writing Rewrite(R) in the line
>   `MyRecursiveASTVisitor(Rewriter &R) : Rewrite(R) { }` assign the value
>   R to the variable Rewrite? There is no class Rewrite defined anywhere
>   in the code. Is the ":" operator used for things other than inheriting
>   from a class?

`Rewrite` is a member variable of your `MyRecursiveASTVisitor` class and is a reference to an object of type `Rewriter`. The `:` operator is used in the definition of a constructor to signify a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). In this case, we simply initialize the `Rewrite` variable with the passed in argument `R`. Just to be clear, `MyRecursiveASTVisitor(Rewriter &R) : Rewrite(R) { }` is a constructor definition for your class `MyRecursiveASTVisitor`, it is **not** the class definition.

---

Answer (score 6):

Its called curiously recurring template pattern. When compiler creates `RecursiveASTVisitor<MyRecursiveASTVisitor>` it knows layout of `MyRecursiveASTVisitor` so its all OK.

You can read more on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)